# How I can make basic UITableCells with the height depending on a text in the label in the cell?

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, uitableview, height

I'm realy new in xcode and i got a problem with the height of my tableViewCell.

I'm useing xcode 4 with storyboard.

I've made a tabel view with basic styled cells in it. In teh cells is one label: cell.textLabel
In this label i show stings which are from a array list. but the lenght of my text is different from cell to cell. How can i make the height of my cell exactly so big, that it shows all the text, and when it's s small text, just the text without a big rand?

I'saw that there are other questions like mine but i don't get it out of them how i can manage it...

thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to change the TableViewCell height.

Or you can use multi-line TableViewCell, link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888749/multi-line-uitableviewcell-using-uitableviewcellstylevalue2-style)