# Rounded rectangle box draw -iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel, cgrect

How could I create this rounded rectangle as shown on the figure? Also my second question is how to get multiple lines , how to format to make it multiple lines as shown in the red rectangle? Thanks in advance!.

```
CGRect viewRect=CGRectMake(30,30,320,55);
UIView *myView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:viewRect];
myView.backGroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:myView]

UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initwithFrame:CGRectMake(30,32,25,12)];
label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:"System" size:12];
label.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:label]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you provided is probably implemented as a `UITableView`. The address cell has the `UITableViewCellStyleValue2` style, which has the `textLabel` on the left ("address") and `detailTextLabel` on the right.

Here's how to format the cell:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell"; 
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = @"address";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"7200—7232 W Orem Dr\nHouston Texas 77085\nUnited States";
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

You'll also have to adjust the height of the cell accordingly, since it will be taller than the default.

**Source:** [Multi-line UITableViewCell using UILabel](http://the-lost-beauty.blogspot.ca/2009/11/multi-line-uitableviewcell-using.html) (via [a similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888749/multi-line-uitableviewcell-using-uitableviewcellstylevalue2-style))